# AngularJS testing controller with async request after event handler (Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine

I've got a controller:

```
myApp.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, myAsyncService, $routeParams) {

    var foo_id = $routeParams.foo_id;

    $scope.foo = 0;
    $scope.bar = false;

    $scope.$on('that_happened',
        function (event, plan) {
            myAsyncService.save({id: foo_id}).$promise.then(function (res) {
                $scope.bar = true;
                $location.path('/foo/' + res.id);
            });
        }
    );

});
```

After 'that_happend' event emitted, service calls async method and I want to test $scope and location changed after callback is executed:

```
describe('my module', function () {
    var res_mock = 2,

        myAsyncService_mock = {
            save: function () {}
        };


    describe('someCtrl', function(){
        var $location,
            $scope,
            $subscope,
            deferred,
            promise_mock,
            ctrl,
            $q;

        beforeEach(
            inject(function ($rootScope, _$location_, _$q_) {
                $q = _$q_;

                $location = _$location_;
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                $subscope = $scope.$new();

                deferred = $q.defer();
                promise_mock = {
                    $promise: deferred.promise
                };


                spyOn(myAsyncService_mock, 'save').andReturn(promise_mock);

                ctrl = $controller('someCtrl',
                    {
                        $scope: $scope,
                        $location: $location,
                        myAsyncService: myAsyncService_mock
                    }
                );

            })
        );


        it('should call save method of service and set bar to true and goto /foo/:saved_foo.id ', function () {

            var saved_foo_mock = {
                    id: 3
                }

            $scope.foo = 11;
            $scope.bar = false;

            $subscope.$emit('that_happened');
            deferred.resolve(saved_foo_mock);

            expect(myAsyncService_mock.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect($scope.bar).toBe(true);
            expect($location.path()).toBe('/foo/' + saved_foo_mock.id);

        });

    });

});
```

But test fails with error 'Expected false to be true'. Seems like promise callback was not executed or was executed after expect();

I've tried to test it the async way, but result is the same - test fails with timeout:

```
runs(function () {
    $scope.bar = false;
    $subscope.$emit('that_happened');
});

waitsFor(function () {
    deferred.resolve(saved_foo_mock);
    return $scope.bar;
}, 'bar should be true', 500);

runs(function () {
    expect(myAsyncService_mock.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/foo/' + saved_foo_mock.id);                
});
```

What's going on? Why $scope and location path are not changed?

Answer (score 0):

That question helped me: [How to test with Jasmine an AngularJS controller that calls service method that returns promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563369/how-to-test-with-jasmine-an-angularjs-controller-that-calls-service-method-that?rq=1)

Moved myAsyncService_mock to beforeEach block and added $scope.$digest call and finally it works:

```
beforeEach(
    inject(function ($rootScope, _$location_, _$q_) {
        .
        .
        .

        myAsyncService_mock = {
            save: function () {
                deferred = $q.defer();
                promise_mock = {
                    $promise: deferred.promise
                };    

                return promise_mock;
            }
        };

        .
        .
        .
    })
);


it('', function(){
    .
    .
    .

    $subscope.$emit('that_happened');
    deferred.resolve(saved_foo_mock);    

    $scope.$digest();

    .
    .
    .
})
```