# Unit test for a funtion in AngularJS controller which calls to a function in Onsen UI with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, onsen-ui

I am making a unit test for a function of a controller in AngularJS code, this function will call to a function in Onsen UI code. But I fail when run it.

My code and my test code as bellow:

**- In app.js file:**

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
 module.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.startpop = function(index) {
    $scope.index = index;
    ons.navigator.popPage();
  };
 }]);
```

**- in test.spec.js file:**

```
describe("test myctrl:", function() {
  var $controller;

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('onsen');
    module('app');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  it('test startpop() function', function() {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('myctrl', {$scope: $scope});
    $scope.startpop(3);

    expect($scope.index).toEqual(3);
 });
```

But I met error when run unit test as bellow:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'popPage' of undefined**

Please help me to solve it ?

Comment: you have to mock `ons.navigator.popPage();` because it seems like it's an external dependecies or service/factory

Comment: I checked it in onsenui.js file, it is a function of module.factory('NavigatorView', ['$http', '$parse', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$onsen', '$timeout', ... . But I don't know how to mock it.

Comment: and how you are using in Controller means are you injecting in Controller or it's a global function??

Comment: I am injecting in Controller

Comment: then create `jasmine.createSpy` for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563369/how-to-test-with-jasmine-an-angularjs-controller-that-calls-service-method-that

Comment: It is not success because controller don't include 'ons' dependency, the dependency of 'ons' is included in module (angular.module('app', ['onsen']);).

Comment: ok fine,but you have to mock /jasmine `ons` function in order to test successfully

Comment: One question, does the code run normally? (other than running it as part of a test)