# How to mock a method which is inside a sub-property of a service?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

The service inside the controller is as follows:

```
 .controller('DesignHomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Service',function($scope,Service){

var home = this;

 home.method1 = function () {
                Service.imageLib.showDialog(options, callback);
            };

   }])
```

As you see the showDialog is inside the sub property.

I don't know how to spyOn on this.

How can I mock it using Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a mock service like

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    service = {
      showDialog: function () {
        //your code
      }
    };
    ...
    spyOn(service, 'showDialog').andCallThrough();
    ...
  }));
```

[this folk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563369/how-to-test-with-jasmine-an-angularjs-controller-that-calls-service-method-that) did something like this